# mount luks volume through pam with gdm

Tags: debian, pam, dm-crypt, gdm3

I'm on debian testing. I encrypted my /home with dm-crypt (luks). Following various tutorials I setup pam_mount to open it at login time. However when I try to login using gdm, it fails. The login screen disappears and reappears shortly after. In /var/log/auth.log I have:

```
Jul 11 00:18:20 yojik gdm-launch-environment]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session opened for user Debian-gdm by vic(uid=0)
Jul 11 00:18:20 yojik gdm-launch-environment]: (pam_mount.c:173): conv->conv(...): Conversation error
Jul 11 00:18:20 yojik gdm-launch-environment]: (pam_mount.c:477): warning: could not obtain password interactively either
Jul 11 00:18:20 yojik gdm-launch-environment]: (mount.c:72): Messages from underlying mount program:
Jul 11 00:18:20 yojik gdm-launch-environment]: (mount.c:76): NOTE: mount.crypt does not support utab (systems with no mtab or read-only mtab) yet. This means that you will temporarily need to call umount.crypt(8) rather than umount(8) to get crypto volumes unmounted.
Jul 11 00:18:21 yojik gdm-launch-environment]: (mount.c:76): crypt_activate_by_passphrase: Operation not permitted
Jul 11 00:18:21 yojik gdm-launch-environment]: (pam_mount.c:522): mount of /dev/disk/by-uuid/d79121a7-5fbd-4484-81d2-6cbdf1b95b5e failed
```

If I switch to a virtual terminal (ctrl-alt-f1) and login there, the /home volume is mounted as expected. I can then go back to gdm and login normally.

So the problem is really in the interaction of gdm and pam_mount. 
I tried to tweak /etc/pam.d/gdm3 following various tutorials and threads... But no success. Most info is pretty old and the only one really updated (Arch linux wiki) seems to have a different implementation of gdm as the files and options have quite different names.

Currently my file looks like this:

```
vic@yojik:~$ cat /etc/pam.d/gdm3
#%PAM-1.0
auth    requisite       pam_nologin.so
auth    required    pam_succeed_if.so user != root quiet_success
@include common-auth
auth    optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so
auth    optional        pam_mount.so

@include common-account

# SELinux needs to be the first session rule. This ensures that any 
# lingering context has been cleared. Without this it is possible 
# that a module could execute code in the wrong domain.
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]       pam_selinux.so close
session optional    pam_mount.so
session required        pam_loginuid.so
# SELinux needs to intervene at login time to ensure that the process
# starts in the proper default security context. Only sessions which are
# intended to run in the user's context should be run after this.
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]       pam_selinux.so open
session required        pam_limits.so
session required        pam_env.so readenv=1
session required        pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
@include common-session
session optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start

@include common-password
```

Question is: how should I modify the file to get the volume mounted with gdm?

EDIT: Here is also `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` (minus the info at the top saying to run `pam-auth-update` to manage the file, which I also did)

```
# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok_secure
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
auth    requisite           pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
auth    required            pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
auth    optional    pam_mount.so 
auth    optional            pam_cap.so 
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

Comment: First, in the `session` section, `pam_mount.so` should go after `common-session`. I don't think it will fix this issue, but it will prevent other issues. Second, can you provide `/etc/pam.d/common-account`?

Comment: Crap, I mean't provide `common-auth`, not `common-account`.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I fixed the order (problem still unsolved) and edited the question to add `/etc/pam.d/common-account`

Comment: Everything looks right. I was hoping to see a `auth sufficient` rule which would be an issue (or other things, but that was most likely). The only other thing I'm seeing is that your log messages indicate the service is `gdm-launch-environment`, but you provided `/etc/pam.d/gdm3`. Is one a symlink to the other?

Comment: You’re right, there was a problem there: `/etc/pam.d/gdm-launch-environment` was a link to `/etc/pam.d/gnome3-autologin`, not to `gdm3` as I had thought. However switching the link and adding `pam_mount.so` to `gdm3` didn’t solve the problem. I think I found the culprit elsewhere… Posting an answer to reflect that. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Problem was in fact in `/etc/security/pam_mount.conf.xml`. Following some tutorial I had inserted the line

`<volume user="*" mountpoint="/home" path="/dev/disk/by-uuid/d79121a7-5fbd-4484-81d2-6cbdf1b95b5e" fstype="crypt" options="fsck" />`

My understanding was that `user="*"` was a regexp-like notation standing for “any user”. Turns out there is no such syntax. So pam_mount was trying to mount the volume for user * and of course failed. This was reflected in the logs by the line `crypt_activate_by_passphrase: Operation not permitted`.

Solved by replacing * with the name of my user. If needed `man pam_mount.conf` has further options for finer grained control.

So if you ever run into problems with `pam_mount` saying `operation not permitted` check that first!